# Why am I not receiving variable from JS to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a variable from JS to php through ajax but I'm not able to get in php file.

JS

```
var names = ['lee','carter'] ;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/test/ajax.php",
    data: {name:names},
}).done(function() {
    location.href = 'http://localhost/test/ajax.php' ;
});
```

PHP

```
print_r($_POST);
```

this is showing an empty array but when I do console.log(data) it shows an array in console.log

```
   var names = ['lee','carter'] ;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/test/ajax.php",
        data: {name:names},
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data) ;
    });
```

**Edit:** *(by mega6382)* I believe OP wants to open a page in browser with post params, which cannot be done by AJAX. All others who answered got mistaken by the AJAX code in the question and started providing AJAX solutions, without realizing what OP is trying to do. If you were to read OP's comments on Jeroen's answer.

Comment: use `echo` to return value from php

Comment: [Understanding ajax tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/ajax-tutorial-web-development-du107rzaq)

Comment: surely if you console.log data and it shows your array - that is what the php ajax file is returning so your data must be getting passed correctly.  The reason the first one doesn't work is because you are redirecting to your ajax.php file after your post has happened so nothing is being posted at that moment in time so your print_r will be an empty array at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ajax try sending a dynamically generated form like:

```
var names = ['lee','carter'] ;
var newForm = $('<form>', {
    'action': "http://localhost/test/ajax.php",
    'target': '_top',
    'method': 'POST'
});
names.forEach(function (item, index)
{
    newForm.append($('<input>', {
        'name': 'name[]',
        'value': item,
        'type': 'hidden'
    }));
});
$(document.body).append(newForm);
newForm.submit();
```

This will send the values over POST via a form. It will do both redirect to the new page and send post vals.

Comment: Why should this necessary at all? From PHP perspective, a POST request is a POST request no matter how it's generated :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I believe OP wanted to open a page in browser with post params, which cannot be done by ajax. All other answerers got mistaken by the ajax code in the question and started providing AJAX solutions, without realizing what OP is trying to do. If you were to read OP's comments on Jeroen's answer, you will see what I am saying.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Also, in the question you can see that `location.href` is a an indicator of what OP wants to do.

Comment: I understand. Then, the question is of course totally misleading :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with what you do when the ajax request finishes:

```
}).done(function() {
    location.href = 'http://localhost/test/ajax.php' ;
});
```

Here you are re-directing to `http://localhost/test/ajax.php` (requesting it a second time...), using a GET request so `$_POST` is indeed empty.

Comment: so how can i send them and receive  on that  php file

Comment: @leecarter That is what the first request - the ajax request - is already doing as you noticed in the second version.

Comment: but in this scenario  other page will not  load

Comment: @leecarter Why would you want to load another page? Using ajax you can send back the information you need and just change part of the content where you want to display the results.

Comment: i am just trying to send variables without submit button  or form tag

Comment: @leecarter You are already doing that. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @leecarter Check my solution, it will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the following in your php file to receive a json formatted string

`echo json_encode(['success' => true]);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an `AJAX` request, in this case `POST`, you could use the `_REQUEST` method in php for obtaining the JS variable. In your case try:

```
 $names = $_REQUEST['name']

 echo $names;

/* Or try JSON_ENCODE if echo isn't working*/

$json = json_encode($names)

echo ($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var names = ['lee','carter'] ;
    JSON.stringify(names);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://localhost/test/ajax.php",
        data: {name:names}
    }).done(function() {
            console.log('ok');
    });
```

This is a successful  ajax call. Now in order to "check by yourself" that is working you don't have to redirect to the other page because that way you refresh and lose the data. What you have to do is:

1. Open developer tab in your browser
2. Go to network tab
3. Locate your ajax call (it has the name of your php class that you do
   the call)
4. go to response tab and there you have your php output

[This link is to help you understand how to debug ajax call](http://prntscr.com/h7s3dp)